# Embeded pdf File is not displaying in Django

Tags: python, html, django, iframe, embed

I was trying to display photos and pdf files in a django project using `<embed>` but pdf file is not displaying 
Here is what i was doing
This is view function

```
@login_required
def view_documents(request):
    students = Student.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    return render(request, 'student/view_documents.html',{'students':students})
```

and then I used for tag in template

```
{% for student in students %}
#lines of code
{% endfor %}
```

and to display the pdf file i have used

```
<embed src="{{student.adhar_card_pdf.url}}" width="800px" height="400px" type="application/pdf"/>
```

but it was showing some kind of error like localhost refused to connect
i also used iframe

```
 <iframe src="{{student.adhar_card_pdf.url}}" style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

But image is displaying in the browser using same code without any error

```
<embed src="{{student.photo_jpg.url}}" width="230px" height="250px" />
```

Why pdf file is not displaying ?? Please help me
Thanx in advance.
Edited: In console it is showing -- Refused to display '' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.
 [This is how it is displaying pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWBZ5.png)

Comment: open up your browser developer tools and tell us the exact error you see. Look at the network tab and check the url it's trying to fetch. Look at your server console and tell us what you see there.

Comment: in console it is showing :  Refused to display '<URL>' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

Answer (score 8):

```
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

Insert the above line in settings.py just before the `MIDDLEWARE` section
and for the file path in embed tag write path as

```
{{student.file.get.photo_jpg.url}}
```

And then give a hard reset in Chrome or any browser you are using.

It worked for me I hope it works for you as well.